# Custom verification emails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise, confirmation, mailer

I am trying to create a sort of recall system where an admin sends a message to the entire user base via email after which all users have to confirm the message by navigating a link in the email (Confirmation token) and retyping the message in. The would a submit button on the page which will check if messages match then clears a confirmation flag in the database. I am stuck on where to even begin here. I am not worried about comparison logic in the controller. I am confused about how to generate the confirmation tokens, sending them, then redirecting users to a page for confirmation. At the moment I am use Devise with Active Admin but I am open any other gem suggestions. If any of you could give me a link to a similar tutorial or problem that would be great! Yes I have done research before asking but it most results had little relevance.

Comment: can admin only create a user?

Comment: Admin can create a user and user can sign up. Admin can only give admin status. I was thinking of rewriting the password reset function to try and get this done though I don't know if its worth the time though

Answer (score 0, accepted):

U could do this with `devise`

I'll share what was recently done by me, which is almost similar to your Q.

I did not use Confirmation link or any token.

> 1. Only Admin can create user.
> 2. On creation of a user, an email is sent along with id and password.
> 3. Upon user login for first time, redirect him to edit account for only password change.

Note: U can use [friendly token](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/blob/master/lib/devise.rb#L476) for generating random password.

Comment: I am not trying to change passwords or have anything to do with them. Instead, I was looking up how to use the process to send out verification emails <--- when a recall is initiated users have to confirm the message sent. Devise has too many thing "implied" or hidden which makes it bit difficult to see everything that is available(Docs don't do it any justice)